# Simplifying the if-else condition using Java Functional Style Programming

Tags: java, optimization, java-8

Any suggestion to simplify the following code block using Java 8 features?

```
int[] ans = new int[2];
list.forEach(i -> {
    if (i > 0) {
        ans[0] += 1;
    } else if (i < 0) {
        ans[1] += 1;
    }
});
```

P.S. Not sure if I should post this [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857232/use-java-lambda-instead-of-if-else ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to count zeros, you code is as simple as it can get. If you wanted to count zeros as positive, however then you could shorten it to this.

```
int[] ans = new int[2];
for (int i : list) ans[i < 0 ? 1 : 0] += 1;
```

Comment: @Eugene There is no `<<<` perhaps you meant `>>>` If you don't know the type of `i` you can use `i >>> -1` which works for `int` and `long`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey ha! had to go to the specification to understand if this is specified or a hack, nice. thank u

Answer (score 2):

```
 ans[0] = (int)list.stream().filter(x -> x < 0).count();
 ans[1] = (int)list.stream().filter(x -> x > 0).count();
```

but I hardly think this is a simplification as such, your solution is already as simple as it can get.

In case you do want to count zeros, this could be simplified to:

```
 list.forEach(x -> ++ans[x >>> 31])
```

Comment: You're actually doing the iteration work twice here aren't you?  I agree there's unlikely to be a simpler solution than the one provided

Comment: @LoztInSpace you are absolutely correct, as said this is hardly a simplification...

Comment: @Eugene, you don't need second iteration. `ans[1] = list.size() - ans[0]`

Comment: @HadiJ I thought about that, but in such a case we don't take `0` into account and the OP's code does

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too.  In C you could go something like `++ans[i>>31]` but those pesky 0s got in the way,

Comment: @LoztInSpace I think you meant `>>>`

Comment: @Eugene Apparently yes!  It's been 15 years since I programmed in Java - I don't think I even knew such an operator exists.  In C you'd get away with it.  All moot of course, because of the 0

Comment: @LoztInSpace well I had no idea about the behavior of the C operator in this case...

Comment: @HadiJ same problem still, if you subtract that count, you end up counting 0s in another bucket.

Comment: `<<<` - what? Do you mean `>>>`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
int[] ans = new int[2];
list.forEach(i -> ans[i >>> 31] += i==0 ? 0 : 1);
```

where `i >>> 31` discards all but the sign bit (i.e., is the same as `i<0 ? 1 : 0`) and the second conditional handles zero.

I don't claim, it's really better than the original.

Comment: You can do it entirely branch-free with `.forEach(i -> ans[i >>> 31] += i>>>31|-i>>>31)`

Comment: @Holger Nice and simple. I guess, I can hope for my conditional being translated using `cmov`, but your expression can be even then faster because of the common subexpression.

Comment: @maaartinus that is *almost* the trick behind `Integer::signum` btw, very good answer still, even without this simplification...1+

Answer (score 1):

To distinguish two cases like `i > 0` and `i < 0`  we can use `Stream.partition`:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> partitioned = list.stream()
  .filter(i -> i != 0)
  .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i > 0));
ans[0] = partitioned.get(true).size();
ans[1] = partitioned.get(false).size();
```

Is it simplified? At least it's still readable and easy to understand.

EDIT
Or as @saka1029 suggests:

```
Map<Boolean, Long> partitioned = list.stream()
  .filter(i -> i != 0)
  .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i > 0, Collectors.counting()));
ans[0] = partitioned.get(true);
ans[1] = partitioned.get(false);
```

EDIT
And a further `Stream` solution which returns the desired array. But I would argue it's not simpler. So it's about to compare.

```
int[] ans = list.stream().filter(i -> i != 0).collect(
  () -> new int[2], 
  (arr, i) -> arr[i > 0 ? 0 : 1]++, 
  (l, r) -> {  l[0] += r[0]; l[1] += r[1]; });
```

Comment: You can collect counts by `.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(i -> i > 0, Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: @saka1029 Thank you for your suggestion. I included it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that counts zeroes as well:

```
int[] ans = new int[3];
list.forEach(i -> ans[Integer.signum(i) + 1] += 1);
```

The `ans` array now holds 3 values: index 0 for negative count, index 1 for zero count and index 2 for positive count.

i.e. for the following input: `[1, 2, 3, 0, -4, -5]`, the output would be: `[2, 1, 3]`.

---

A more functional way, excluding zeroes:

```
Map<Integer, Long> bySignum = list.stream()
    .filter(i -> i != 0)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Integer::signum, Collectors.counting()));
```

Which produces this output: `{-1=2, 1=3}`.

Comment: well, if you happen to know how `Integer::signum` is implemented, `i >> 31 | -i >>> 31` - which is sort of crazy how smart it is, you could say `ans[i >>> 31] = i >>> 31 | -i >>> 31` as Holger has shown above. The explanation for this is interesting too. if `i` is negative, `i >>> 31` will give `1` (index), if `i` is positive `i >>> 31` will give `0`. that is the index computation. and the part `i >>> 31 | -i >>> 31` is even funner!!

Comment: @Eugene Well, yeah, it's clever, I guess. I wouldn't sacrifice code readability for this, it's OK if we're just having fun (this is the modern equivalent of playing crosswords), And it is `ans[i >>> 31] += i >>> 31 | -i >>> 31` (you forgot the `+`sign)