# How to find the sum of divisors using Java streams?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert this function to use Java 8 new syntax. Hopefully it will reduce the number of lines and perhaps make things clearer.

```
public int divisorSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i ++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            sum = Integer.sum(sum, i);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I tried this:

```
IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(i -> ... )
```

But according to a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49857232/10597330) by Tezra apparently it is not advisable to loop using lambdas.

Comment: Can you share how you attempted to solve the problem?

Comment: Really? `sum = Integer.sum(sum, i);` instead of `sum = sum + i;` or `sum += i;`?

Comment: @Holger I read it somewhere in someone's code and I thought it was cool! There is also this one. `max = Math.max(4, 5)`. Awesome, right?

Comment: `Math.max(a, b)` can be considered a simplification over `a >= b? a: b`, not to speak of the required code for the floating point case, unlike `Integer.sum(a, b)` versus `a + b`.

Comment: @Holger `sum = Integer.sum(sum, a)` looks more readable compared to `sum += a`. No need to comprehend `+=`. You can read it in plain english: "Integer, then sum them". Especially for English speakers who read from left to right. `+=` is more like reading right to left. And there is no english word for it AFAIK

Comment: Since the operand order doesn’t matter for addition, it makes no sense to discuss whether it is read left to right or right to left. It’s the *assignment* which is right to left, *in all these cases*. And if you don’t like the `+=` operator, just use plain `+`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the Java 8 streams implementation:

```
public int divisorSum(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).filter(i -> n % i == 0).sum();
}
```

Note that `rangeClosed`, like your example, *includes `n`*. `range()` excludes the second parameter (it would only include up to `n-1`).

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve the same result using `IntStream`, `filter` and `IntStream::sum` that directly returns `int` since this stream is unboxed:

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n).filter(i -> n % i == 0).sum();
```

Comment: because it implements the proper interface? jokes aside, I don't understand either.

Comment: .. or I didn't put it into the method. it makes me doubt my abilities to write Java code :/ I really would like to know if there is something wrong in my answer

Comment: don't. move on. get used to random downvotes, without comments, they mean ZERO, or at least should to your personal feelings.

Comment: @Nikolas Maybe if you're wondering why I didn't accept your answer over MyStackRunnethOver's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61086405/10597330) who answered later, it was because SO kept refusing me from accepting your answer saying I should wait. When MyStackRunnethOver posted his, it was a lot more descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this

```
public static int divisorSum(int n) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
            .filter(i -> n % i == 0)
            .sum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be helpful.

```
int sum1 = java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1, n + 1).filter(x -> n % x == 0).reduce(0, (x, y) -> x + y);
```

or

```
int sum1 = java.util.stream.IntStream.range(1, n + 1).filter(x -> n % x == 0).sum();
```